# Password is required every time I open Laptop Lid - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, login, password

Every time when I close and open the lid of my Laptop, Ubuntu asks for password, which is very annoying.

Can I get rid of it? I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3):

Under the Settings (Gear Icon in launcher), click on the Brightness and Lock icon and at the bottom of it's window, uncheck the "Require a password when coming back from suspend".